# CLLocation with wifi and Mobile data

Tags: location, wifi, long-integer, cllocation

Hi I am developing app which works on current location. But with Wifi it gives me correct current location, but when I switch to mobile data it gives me wrong location, around 643 meter away. How can I get same location with mobile data. Please help asps. Thanks in advance.